# How to remove iOS 8 extensions?

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I am having a problem. I tested the extensions in my application and I can't get rid of them now.
I tried deleting the application, cleaning the project, opening in simulator, other device but this problem persists.
I don't have targets and the files in the project but still the share options appear and i can't disable them. Is this a bug or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i found that if you don't remove files from your project folder this happens. I just deleted the folders that contained the story-boards, .m and .h files and i don't see the problem again.